# How to change the url of the standard spring security config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using pretty standard spring security:

`http.csrf().disable()
.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler)`

And i can login by doing a post to `/login` however i want to change this url to `/api/login` but i can't find out how.

Anyone that knows how?

Comment: are you doing a form login ?

Comment: I am logging in by doing a rest post with a json payload containing username and password. Not sure if this is what you mean with form login